# How to create a proper 503 Maintenance page in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, seo

I want to create a proper maintenance page for my site in MVC.  I want it to return status code 503 so google will come back to index it later.

So far, i've created an ActionFilter that checks to see if "MaintenanceMode" is TRUE in the web.config.  If it is (and we're not already going to the maintenance page), it does a simple redirect to ~/Maintenance/.  Can I do something so 503 is returned during all of this, or is that not possible?

Just to add, I have a secret query string parameter that you can type in and it creates a cookie for 40 minutes that bypasses the maintenance screen.  Just mentioning it in case you are wondering why I have this screen to begin with...

UPDATED:

I can't figure out how to return a 503 status code with a page of my choosing (a "Be right back!" page)... but I know how to return a 503 with the ugly version:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 503;
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(503);
```

I might go with this for now.  If someone can confirm that i'm thinking correctly here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I figured this out on my own.  I was going the wrong way about it...

I was trying to create a friendly 503 page within the context of MVC framework.  Instead, I simply created a 503.htm file and put it in the root.  I then configured IIS (on my hosting) to do a 503 error redirect to 503.htm.

When my website is up, and in maintenance mode, I have an actionfilter that does this:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(503);
```

But before I go there, I check if a "secret" querystring was entered.  If it was, I create a maintenance cookie for 40 minutes and I let the user circumvent the 503 so he can test/play with the site.

This is how i achieved a 503 maintenance page while still being able to test the site.